# Pointer of number in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Assume there's function that get `int *` parameter.

```c
void foo(int *x)
{
    
}
```

If I want to call this function without creating an int variable

```c
int main()
{
    foo(&1);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation fails and I get this error message:

```
lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Why 1 has no address? Isn't that stored in stack ?

Comment: 1 ist not a variable, it's a value, it cannot have an address.

Comment: The error says it all. Constants literals are not 'lvalues'.

Comment: Please show all the code.

Comment: @user8469759 but string constants have addresses what is the difference ?

Comment: @gregspears updated.

Comment: A string constant is not a simple primitive value, it intrinsically a pointer to some data baked into the executable. A more sensible comparison is to a `const`, if your C compiler has those.

Comment: @user8469759 `1` is not *"constant literal"* only **constant expression**.  Literal is something completely different.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. So if function get only int parameter, not the address of int, how it passed to function if it is not stored?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why 1 has no address? Isn't that stored in stack ?

No - it is just a value.

You need an object to take its address (reference). A constant expression is not such an object.

You can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) to create temporary object:

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    printf("%d\n", *x);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo( (int[]){1} );
    foo( &(int){1} );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xvdbTzn3Y

> but string constants have addresses what is the difference ?

They are not constant expressions only [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). String literal is an array of ``` char``[C] ``` or ``` const char``[C++] ```. String literals cannot be modified (it invokes undefined behabior) . It is an object and you can take the address of it:

```
void foo(char (*x)[])
{
    printf("'%s'\n", *x);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(&"dsfgdfsgdfg");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q9s3P6xcb

Comment: Impressively confusing for C!

Comment: It's like a shortcut creating an array and pass it to the function right?

Comment: @Ertugrul It creates ***temporary*** object. The first one has type of array of `int` elements ans decays to pointer. The second one has type `int` and you need to take its refeence by using `&` operator

Comment: You may wish to avoid calling it a “temporary” object. Its lifetime ends when execution of its associated block ends (for a compound literal inside a function). C has a temporary lifetime for a returned structure or union that contains an array, and it ends when evaluation of its containing full expression ends.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are 100% right. I use the word *temporary* to make it easier for OP to imagine what it is. If you have a better word in mind I will replace it.

Comment: I would add that compound literals need not be temporary objects. They are essentially anonymous static variables when they occur outside a function's scope. It's really neat.

Answer (score 2):

The operand of the unary `&` operator must be an *lvalue*, which is an expression that designates an *object* such that the object's contents may be read or modified.  Examples of lvalues would be variable names like `x` or `q` or `someLongVariableName`, array subscript expressions like `arr[i]`, member selection operations like `foo.bar` or `fptr->bar`, or combinations of the above like `arr[i].ptr->member`.

Anything that can can appear on the left side of a `=` operator is an lvalue (and can potentially be an operand of unary `&`).

Your problem is that the expression `1` is not an lvalue; it's a *constant expression*, and as such usually doesn't have any associated storage, so it has no address.

Comment: I would rather say that constant expression never has any storage duration.